# Javascript regex ending word not found

Tags: javascript, regex

[In this regex](http://regexr.com/3b0pu) , I need to match an ending word that starts with `'(', ')'` or `','`.

Regex :

```
/[\(\),].*$/
```

For example, given the text `(aaa,bbb)ccc` I need to obtain `)ccc`. Still, it returns the entire text. What's wrong with this regex?

Comment: Just remove `\(` from your regex.

Comment: Use this `/[\)].*$/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
'(aaa,bbb)ccc'.match(/[(),][^(),]+$/)
//=> [")ccc"]
```

`[^(),]+` is **negation pattern** that matches any character but any listed in `[^(),]`.

Problem with `[(),].*$` is that it matches very first `(` in input and matches till end.

Comment: why don't you escape the parenthesis?

Comment: Inside character class parenthesis or any other special meta character e.g. dot, `*` etc don't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider using capturing group while consuming all the characters up to the first `(`, `)` or `,`:

```
.*([(),].*)$
```

`.*` will consume as many characters as it can, then any character in this character class `[(),]`, and then the rest of the characters up to the end.

The `)ccc` value will be stored in Group 1:

```js
var re = /.*([(),].*)$/; 
var str = '(aaa,bbb)ccc';
 
if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = m[1];
}
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://regexr.com/3b0q4) regex:

```
/[(,)][^(,)]*$/
```